# Алгоритм Diffie–Hellman

Tags: php, java, c++, любой-язык, теория

Господа, прошу пояснить теорию ( математику ), дабы используя PHP я сам набросал код

[есть статья как поменяться ключами](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange), совершенно не понимаю почему описанный обмен данными безопасен с точки зрения тех, кто обменивается ключами. Прошу объяснить!

p.s.

```
Алиса: знает P=23, G=5, A=6
Боб: знает P=23, G=5, B=15
Погон: знает P=23, G=5 и прослушивает канал связи
.. погнали ..

Алиса: отсылает бобу 8 ( 5^6/23 = что-то и остаток 8 )
Погон: знает что отослала Алиса
Боб: видит 8
Погон: знает что получил Боб
Боб: отсылает Алисе 19 ( 5^15/23 = что-то и остаток 19 )
Погон: знает что отослал Боб
Алиса: видит 19
Погон: знает что получила Алиса
.. теперь Погон знает столько же сколько и остальные ..

Алиса: вычисляет, 19^6/23 = что-то и остаток 2
Погон: вычисляет, 19^6/23 = что-то и остаток 2
Боб: вычисляет, 8^15/23 = что-то и остаток 2
Погон: вычисляет, 8^15/23 = что-то и остаток 2
.. теперь Погон знает столько же сколько и остальные ..

если коротко:
Алиса -> 8 -> Боб -> 19 -> Алиса ( Погон знает тоже самое )
```

Comment: блин, у меня была надежда ) Спасибо, что объяснили

Comment: @goldstar_labs Это неверно, весь смысл Diffie–Hellman в том, что априори стороны не могут иметь никакого "секретного большого числа".

Comment: @VTT вы правы, я перепутал

Comment: @gforce как Погон может вычислять "19^6/23" или "8^15/23" для получения итогового секретного значения 2, если он не знает ни A=6, ни B=15?

Comment: Зачем Погону вычислять 19^6/23 и 8^15/23, если он и так типа уже знает про 6 и 15?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.. теперь Погон знает столько же сколько и остальные .. [1]
```

А вот и нет. Ему по-прежнему **не**известны `A=6` и `B=15`. Эти числа не передавались по каналам связи, передавались только "производные с потерями", сделать обратную операцию по которым невозможно за разумное время.

Посему эти два шага Погон осуществить не сможет, у него нет всех деталей:

```
Погон: вычисляет, 19^6/23 = что-то и остаток 2
                     ^ нету
Погон: вычисляет, 8^15/23 = что-то и остаток 2
                    ^^ нету
```

Comment: goldstar_labs в комменте так и написал ( который удалил ) , что изначально A и B не известны пользователю Погон, это было непонятно для меня в статье на Wiki

Comment: @gforce но это же прямо написано в самом примере.

Answer (score 2):

В данном примере допущена ошибка:

```
Алиса: знает P=23, G=5, B=6 
Боб: знает P=23, G=5, A=15
Погон: знает P=23, G=5 и прослушивает канал связи
.. погнали ..
```

лучше бы A=6 пометить прописной **a=6**, соответственно **b=6**.

Тогда исправленный пример выглядел бы так:

```
Алиса: знает P=23, G=5, a=6
Боб: знает P=23, G=5, b=15
Погон: знает P=23, G=5 и прослушивает канал связи
.. погнали ..

Алиса: отсылает бобу 8 ( A=P^a mod G = 5^6 mod 23 = 8 )
Погон: знает что A=8, но он не знает a
Боб: видит A=8
Погон: знает что получил Боб
Боб: отсылает Алисе B=19 ( B=P^b mod G = 5^15 mod 23 = 19 )
Погон: знает что отослал Боб
Алиса: видит B=19
Погон: знает что получила Алиса
.. Погон знает P, G, A, B. Алиса знает P, G, A, B, a. Боб знает P, G, A, B, b ..

Алиса: вычисляет, K = A^b mod P = 19^6 mod 23 = 2
Погон: для того, чтобы найти K ему нужно либо a, либо b. Он знает, что A=P^a mod G, но найти a можно только перебором, при достаточно большом a это нереально сделать за адекватное время.
Боб: вычисляет, K = B^a mod P = 8^15 mod 23 = 2
Погон: смотрите выше
.. теперь у Боба и Алисы есть общий ключ, а погон его не знает ..
```

То есть у нас есть алгоритм, который помогает вырабатывать общий секрентый ключ. Он защищен от прослушивания, но он не защитит нас в ситуации, когда человек посередине(Погон) сможет подменять сообщения: он сможет подменить пересланные A, B.